Appropriate regression model for total time spent (duration) as a dependent variable
In my study, participants analyzed nine different soundtracks, divided into three conditions: Condition 1 (first 3 tracks), Condition 2 (middle 3 tracks), and Condition 3 (final 3 tracks). While listening, they adjusted a slider from 0 to 10 to indicate their perception. The slider's midpoint (5) represents "Neutral," values above 5 indicate perceiving one sound (S1) with varying intensities, and values below 5 indicate perceiving another sound (S2), also with varying intensities. Each condition features different sounds, and track lengths vary among conditions.
I have already analyzed the continuous slider data (representing perceived intensity). However, I am now interested in the total time spent in each slider zone: Neutral (value = 5), S1 (value > 5), and S2 (value < 5). This approach discretizes the data, allowing me to assess total durations for Neutral, S1, and S2 across conditions. The idea is whether the total time spent in each zone depends on the conditions.
My question is, what would be the appropriate regression model to do such analysis? I've first tested linear mixed-effects models, but confidence intervals show negative values. So I've read about Poisson and negative binomial regression, but aren't they for count data? I also thought of using proportions, but what would be the approach if my values are bounded between 0 and 1? I've also tested multinomial logistic regression to see if there is an increase in the odds of finding a specific category in function of the conditions, but I was interested in the total time spent in each. I've controlled for the length of the tracks by using it as a fixed effect. So what would be the correct approach here?
Here is some random data based on the real one, and an example code of what I've tested so far:
track_nb  participant  S2  S1  neutral condition
        1            1 121 275       56        C1
        1            2 195 138       95        C1
        1            3 274  22       19        C1
        2            1 199 266       98        C1
        2            2 116 182       84        C1
        2            3 101 109       20        C1
        3            1 115 253       31        C1
        3            2 173  78       80        C1
        3            3  47 265       96        C1
        4            1  35 175       52        C2
        4            2  96 205       37        C2
        4            3 297 236       97        C2
        5            1 137  54       52        C2
        5            2  48 261       79        C2
        5            3 110 189       40        C2
        6            1 142 233       79        C2
        6            2 209 208       26        C2
        6            3 173  33       42        C2
        7            1 202 206       51        C3
        7            2 106  94       10        C3
        7            3  59 196       94        C3
        8            1 267 268       69        C3
        8            2 262 109       93        C3
        8            3 225 171       21        C3
        9            1 129 220       25        C3
        9            2  30 126       86        C3
        9            3  92 100       31        C3

library(tidyr)
library(lme4)
library(glmmTMB)

test <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(S2, S1, neutral),         
    names_to = "category",              
    values_to = "total_time_spent"                 
  )

#linear mixed-effects

m1 <- lmer(total_time_spent ~ condition * category + category:length + (1 | participant), REML = FALSE, data = test)

#example of the negative binomial

model_durations_interaction <- glmmTMB(total_time_spent ~ condition * category + category:length + (1 | participant), 
                                    family = nbinom2,
                                    REML = FALSE, data = test)

Thank you!
